# Goddady Domain delegated to wix: add subdomain to No-IP

Tags: dns, godaddy, dynamic-dns, wix

I have purchased a domain in GoDaddy and delegated to my client's website created in Wix and is working OK.

Now my client wants to add some subdomains that points to a local machine on his network using NO-IP.

I need to delegate that subdomain to No-IP and keep the main site in Wix.
Is that possibly?

Comment: Are these sub-domains to be accessed via the Internet or just for internal use?

Comment: Also, if your are using NO-IP the company, your solution will come from them. Normally, a sub-domain is assigned using an A record within the DNS. If you are using GoDaddy for your DNS then dynamic IP is available through GoDaddy. I suggest starting there.

Answer (score 2):

> I need to delegate [a number of subdomains] to No-IP and keep the main site in Wix. Is that possible?

From this [Wix Support article](https://support.wix.com/en/article/pointing-vs-name-servers-domain-connection), it seems [Wix allows you to point a domain at them via an A record](https://support.wix.com/en/article/tutorial-connecting-your-domain-by-pointing-to-ip) while keeping DNS under your control or [you can allow them to manage DNS directly for the domain](https://support.wix.com/en/article/connecting-a-domain-to-the-wix-name-servers).

The choice between these method of connecting the domain to Wix will have an effect on accomplishing your client's goal.

Assuming the client wishes to use No-IP as a dynamic DNS provider, you have a few options.

**Wix DNS**

- [Set up a redirect in Wix](https://support.wix.com/en/article/using-a-subdomain-to-connect-an-external-resource-eg-a-blog-to-your-wix-domain) from the subdomain to the No-IP URL e.g. *sub.noipdomain.com* (this can potentially change the URL in the browser).

**Wix Pointing**

- Set up a redirect in GoDaddy from the subdomain to the No-IP URL e.g. *sub.noipdomain.com*  (this can potentially change the URL in the browser).
- Purchase "managed" DNS services from No-IP so they can control the DNS for *example.com* directly and thus dynamically update *sub.example.com* via their update program. You will need to update GoDaddy's nameserver settings in this case.

As a suggestion, for the second Wix Pointing option, you also may want to investigate [Namecheap FreeDNS](https://www.namecheap.com/store/domains/freedns). As its name implies, it is currently free and should provide the same basic functionality as the paid No-IP option above (they have a [dynamic DNS client](https://www.namecheap.com/support/knowledgebase/article.aspx/111/11/using-namecheap-dynamic-dns-client--version-20x-beta)).